# How to avoid redirect url screen after oauth completes using xamarin.auth for Linkedin Sign-in?

Tags: xamarin.forms, linkedin-api, xamarin.auth

I have sign-in in LinkedIn using xamarin.auth.
After Oauth completes successfully, redirect url screen is coming for 1 second instead of directly going in app screen.
After 1 second, app screen is coming.
How can I avoid this redirect url screen.

I have used below code:

```
var authenticator = new OAuth2Authenticator(
StringConstants.LinkedInClientId,
StringConstants.ClientSecret,
StringConstants.Scope,
new Uri(StringConstants.AuthorizeUrl),
new Uri(redirectUrl),
new Uri(StringConstants.AccessTokenUrl));
```

//redirectUrl is valid website url.

```
authenticator.Completed += OnAuthCompleted;
authenticator.Error += OnAuthError;
authenticator.ShowErrors = false;
var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
presenter.Login(authenticator);
```

After above log-in call I get call back in folowing method::

```
void OnAuthCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
Account account = 
store.FindAccountsForService(DeploymentConstants.AppTitle).FirstOrDefault();
var authenticator = sender as OAuth2Authenticator;
if (authenticator != null)
{
authenticator.Completed -= OnAuthCompleted;
authenticator.Error -= OnAuthError;
}
if (e.IsAuthenticated)
{
 var values = e.Account.Properties;
var access_token = values["access_token"];
Settings.AuthData = access_token;
if (account != null)
{
 store.Delete(account, DeploymentConstants.AppTitle);
}
store.Save(account = e.Account, DeploymentConstants.AppTitle);
}

}
```

Then in further flow I m calling:
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();

Please guide.

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like? I'm sorry, but we can't help you based only on this. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to ask a proper question.

Comment: I have update my question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use "Embedded WebView" and not "Native UI".

In "Embedded WebView" Xamarin.Auth loaded `redirect_url` in the WebView, so that OAuth parameters could be parsed by the API. I cannot tell why it takes 1 sec - most likely javascript on `redirect_url`. Try changing it some other "valid website url" and compare times.